# Get method from a DB results in socket hang up error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to get an array of all users from my database. It results in the socket hang up error. Could anyone help? Thank you!
Here is the link to the project on Glitch: [Glitch project](https://glitch.com/~exercise-tracker-lm)
Here comes the problematic code:

```js
app.get("/api/exercise/users", (req, res) => {
  userModel.find({}), (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send("Error reading the database.");
      } else {
        let nameAndId = data.map(user => {
           return { username: user.username, id: user._id };
        });
        res.send(nameAndId);
      }
    };
});
```

Here is the errror:

```js
/opt/debugger/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy/1.16.2/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:119
    throw err;
    ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:364:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at TCP._handle.close (net.js:597:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the way you are listening on the server. Try:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: I solved it, there was a syntax mistake. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! A simple mistake, this is working code:

```js
app.get("/api/exercise/users", (req, res) => {
  userModel.find({}, ( err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send("Error reading the database.");
      } else {
        let nameAndId = data.map(user => {
           return { username: user.username, id: user._id };
        });
        res.send(nameAndId);
      }
    });
});
```